# want to understand following error

Tags: jquery

[image: Error in Debugging]

Webpage error details are as follow..

```
    User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)Timestamp: Sat, 14 Apr 2018 06:04:41 UTC 

   Message: Expected identifier
   Line: 3887
   Char: 4
   Code: 0
   URI: https://www.icegate.gov.in/scripts/jquery.js


 Message: Expected identifier, string or number
 Line: 95
 Char: 5
 Code: 0
 URI: https://www.icegate.gov.in/scripts/MetroJs.lt.js
```

Second Error i am getting is

Webpage error details

```
 User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;  Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Sat, 14 Apr 2018 06:05:55 UTC

 Message: Expected identifier
 Line: 3887
 Char: 4
 Code: 0
 URI: https://www.icegate.gov.in/scripts/jquery.min.js


  Message: Object expected
  Line: 13
  Char: 1
  Code: 0
  URI: https://www.icegate.gov.in/iceLogin/


  Message: Object expected
  Line: 18
  Char: 2
  Code: 0
  URI: https://www.icegate.gov.in/iceLogin/
```

[image: error 2]

Please guide me to solution of this error. i am new to all this stuff.

Comment: If you are new to that stuff, you might be interested in learning [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your jQuery file looks corrupted.

Comment: I suggest that you hide the URL of the website you are working on, and post the actual code with the error, not a screenshot. Most likely you haven't imported jQuery properly, and when you do all the errors will disappear.